# Remove JSON attributes if not found in defined array

Tags: javascript

I need to remove attribute from the `meta` if it's not exist in `att`

for example : `cardNo` is not existing in the `att`

```
const att = ['id', 'name','class'];
const meta =  [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "test",
     "cardNo": 23
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "test2",
     "cardNo": 232
   }

];
```

Expected output:

```
[
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "test",
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "test2"
   }

];
```

Comment: What's with people down-voting? Comment why if you down-vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ramda.js (https://ramdajs.com/docs/) to make it easier:

```
const att = ['id', 'name','class'];
const meta =  [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "test",
     "cardNo": 23
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "test2",
     "cardNo": 232
   }

]

const onlyAtts = map(pick(att), meta)
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because rest of the solution removing the attribute if some of  attributes values are null or empty. using this solution null and '' not be removed thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
   for(let data of meta){
    for (let key of Object.keys(data)) {
           if (arr.indexOf(key) == -1) {
               delete obj[key];
           }
    }    }
```

Comment: FYI the question has nothing to do with NodeJS and it's just a plain javascript

Answer (score 1):

i think this is the answer for your question.

```js
const att = ['id', 'name','class'];
const meta =  [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "test",
     "cardNo": 23
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "test2",
     "cardNo": 232
   }

];

let newMeta = meta.map((d) => {
    let obj = {};
    att.forEach((currentAtt) => {
    if(d.hasOwnProperty(currentAtt)) {
        obj[currentAtt] = d[currentAtt];
    }
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(newMeta);
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can easily achieve this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const att = ["id", "name", "class"];
const meta = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "test",
    cardNo: 23,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "test2",
    cardNo: 232,
  },
];

const result = meta.map((obj) => {
  const perfectObj = att.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (obj[curr]) {
      acc[curr] = obj[curr];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return perfectObj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also works

```js
const att = ['id', 'name','class'];
const meta =  [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "test",
     "cardNo": 23
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "test2",
     "cardNo": 232
   }

];

function compare(meta, fields) {

    meta.map(object => {
        let dataKeys = Object.keys(object);
        dataKeys.forEach(element => {
            if(fields.indexOf(element) < 0) {
                delete object[element];
            }
        });
    });

}

compare(meta, att);
console.log(meta);
```